# Ruby. NUL chars after reading simple file

Tags: ruby

I'm reading simple text files using Ruby for further regex processing and suddenly I see that str `NUL` after each printable character. Totally lost, where it comes from, I tested typing simple text in  Notepad, saving as txt file and still getting those. I'm on W machine, didn't have this before.
How I can process it, probably replace them, not sure how to refer to them.
My regex doesn't work with them, tried several ways, using SciTE for run.
e.g.  `use` presented as `uNULsNULeNUL` and not equal to `use`

```
puts File.read(file_name)
puts '____________________'

File.open(file_name, "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    puts 'Line.....' + line
  end
end
```

---------------------- below pic on content of file and output:
[image]

Comment: What encoding is the file in? What encoding are you reading it as? Are the two the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file is probably in UTF-16 format. You'll need to read it in that way:

```
File.open(file_name, "r:UTF-16LE") do |f|
  # ...
end
```

That format is the default in Windows.

You can always fix this by re-saving the file as UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks TadM and J,  tried but got error, let me try find right encoding.  file travelled from some old TFS/ SQL Server. Is there any way to convert it in single shot.

Comment: Tx again, at least I learned what problem is , I have more then 1 bad encodings, so need come up with logic find them first and try to do `str.force_encoding(“SHIFT-JIS”).encode!` ..something.

Comment: Sounds like you've got multiple layers of encoding issues. Hope you can sort through it. This is why it's strongly encouraged to use UTF-8 as often as you can, it's much less irritating than having to force-switch codepages.

Comment: Tx T, yes, I'm looking into solution go thru all file system first and do save all into UTF, not sure if it' s cb'e done in Ruby, probably in some PShell..

Comment: it was  IBM437 !!!,  I found perfect  solution by SR(c) like on https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Convert-Files-To-UTF-8-5c58db5e